# railsでdeviseを使ってsign_inする際に名前でサインインできない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

railsでdeviseを使ってログイン画面を作成しているのですが名前、パスワード、Eメール全て入力しても名前だけがなぜか利用できないような状態になってしまいます。

解決としてやってみたことはcustomer.rbのバリデーションを確認したりvalidates :nameをpresenceに書き換えたりしてみても変わらず

customerのmodelもnameデータがないか確認しましたがnameもあるし何が原因なのかよくわかりません。

どなたかこのエラーについてお分かり頂ける方がいましたら回答よろしくお願い致します。

エラー内容

```
1 error prohibited this customer from being saved:_Name can't be blank
```

model/customer.rb

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
         with_options presence: true do
          validates :name, presence: true
            validates :status
            end
        enum status: {
          normal: 0,
          withdrawn: 1,
          banned: 2
          }
        end
```

model/customer.rb

```
 create_table "customers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.string "name", null: false
    t.integer "status", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_customers_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_customers_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end
```